# Taking values from one dataframe into another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe with information about journeys, and another with information about locations and zones.

```
     Origin       Coordinates     Time
0    Victoria     x,y             15:32
1    Wembley      x,y             14:00
2    Canary Wharf x,y             11:00
3    Stratford    x,y             09:00




     Station    Zone
0    Victoria   1
1    Waterloo   1
2    Stratford  2
```

I want to take information from the second dataframe, and add a 'OriginZone' column to the first dataframe, with the appropriate zone.

So far I have tried the following:

```
def getZone(Station):
    return stations[stations.Station == Station]['Zone'].values[0]


df['OriginZone'] = getZone(df['Origin'])
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

First of all, why am I getting this error? And how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your dataframes. If your first dataframe is `df_1` and your second is `df_2`, try this:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, left_on = 'Origin', right_on='Station', how='left').drop('Station', axis=1)
```

Which returns:

```
         Origin Coordinates   Time  Zone
0      Victoria         x,y  15:32   1.0
1       Wembley         x,y  14:00   NaN
2  Canary Wharf         x,y  11:00   NaN
3     Stratford         x,y  09:00   2.0
```

Note, the `NaN`s are there because you are missing `Zone` data in your `df_2` for those stations.

**Explanation**: This uses `merge`, which combines your two dataframes where `df_1['Origin']` matches `df_2['Station']`. I selected `how = 'left'` so that it does not drop rows from the left dataframe (`df_1`) where data is missing, and finally, dropped the extra `Station` column, which is not needed for your purposes.

As for why you are getting this error, I think there are a few things that your code is trying to do that is not working, but the main one that jumps out at me is that you are calling `getZone` with a `pd.Series` as the argument, and so it is trying to compare your `stations` dataframe (which in your example is of length 4) to your `df['Origin']` (which is of length 3). Even if the lengths and indices matched, though, I'm not sure this would achieve what you wanted. You could potentially do it with a loop and a `.loc` statement, but this would be clunky. `merge` exists for these reasons!